# How to parse Date in IST format in Golang?

Tags: parsing, time, go

```
time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), time.Now().Day(), 10, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
```

I want to set dateTime of 10:00:00 AM in IST format in golang.

Comment: What is your exact time format you want to parse?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the format of the time you have at hand. Go has some standard time formats ready as consts in the `time` package, but you can specify your own standard if it's custom. Regarding the time zone, you can parse or output a time in a specific time zone. Here is an example of parsing a time string in IST, and outputting it as UTC. It's not clear from your question what is your precise problem but I hope this helps:

```
// First, we create an instance of a timezone location object
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")

// this is our custom format. Note that the format must point to this exact time
format := "Jan _2 2006 3:04:05 PM"

// this is your timestamp
timestamp := "Jun 25 2015 10:00:00 AM"

// now we parse it, considering it's in IST
t, err := time.ParseInLocation(format, timestamp,  loc)

// printing it prints it in IST, but you can set the timezone to UTC if you want
fmt.Println(t, err)

// example - getting the UTC timestamp
fmt.Println(t.UTC())
```

Comment: Thanks Senhor Golfer, I didn't know about time.ParseInLocation(). For future readers, another useful function to be aware of is time.In().